# Yii2 migrations and Git branching

Tags: model, yii2, crud, database-migration, git-branch

A simple question on Git branching and Yii2 database migrations.
While developing, sometimes there is a need to change the database.
I then make a new migration, and I run the Model generator, and the CRUD
generator anew - where all the controller, model and view files are overwritten.
I then manually merge in my old code into the new. A tedious task but at least I know what
I'm doing.
But, I have Git. I have never tried the branching/merge capabilities of Git. 
Could I just create a new branch, to which the Model/CRUD generated code goes,
and then merge that branch to master? What are the logical steps in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - **Yes, you can**.

Using migrations, you can easily have different versions of your database, as well as code. When developing a new feature, you create a new branch e.g. `git checkout -b feature/new_table`, and work in it.

If you need a new database table, you [create a new migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#creating-migrations) like this

```
$ ./yii migrate/create create_featured_table_table
```

In a new file, you describe a procedure of creating table - `up()` 
and removing it - `down()`.

If there are any additional changes in database state in `up()`, you should  revert them in `down()` function.

When migration is ready, you can `migrate/up` to apply changes and use new table for CRUD generation. All changes are only exist in your branch.

You can merge this branch into master without any problems, because your database is already in actual state.

But if you need to checkout master or other branch without merging changes, you should `migrate/down` at first. By doing this, you set database to previous state, so it's not affected by you current branch.

When you get back to your feature branch, `migrate/up` again and all changes in database will appear.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes, that seems very plausible, will give it a try.

Comment: doing this with multiple collegues will get really complex FAST. I recommend 1 (one) migration per team at the same time. If one team member is working on a feature with a migration, wait for it to be merged in the main branch and update your feature branch before you make your own migration. The above mentioned procedure is possible but there are still a lot of pitfalls.